# QGIS view raster with no CRS without on the fly reprojection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, sar

I have RADARSAT-2 imagery which is georeferenced with Rational Polynomial Coefficients (RPCs), but is not orthorectified. QGIS will reproject/resample the raster to a defined CRS like EPSG:4326, however there are time where I would like to view the raw raster without reprojection. Is this possible? I have tried setting the project CRS to unknown/no projection but the raster will still be reprojected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if opening a raster layer that has some kind of georeferencing metadata such as GCPs or RPCs, QGIS will use the CRS of those metadata items to do the on-the-fly reprojection.

As a workaround, it is possible to create a VRT with those metadata stripped to ensure that the imagery is rendered without reprojection.